# How can I maximize a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, pulp

How i can maximize an objective function?

I have a list of customers and each of them can be "activated" in three different ways.

```
n= 1000
df = pd.DataFrame(list(range(0,n)), columns = ['Customer_ID'])
df['A'] = np.random.randint(2, size=n)
df['B'] = np.random.randint(2, size=n)
df['C'] = np.random.randint(2, size=n)
df['check_somma'] = df['A']+df['B']+df['C']
for index, rows in df[df['check_somma'] == 0].iterrows():
    i = np.random.randint(3)
    if i == 0:
        df.loc[index,['A']]= 1
    if i == 1:
        df.loc[index,['B']]= 1
    if i == 2:
        df.loc[index,['C']]= 1
df['check_somma'] = df['A']+df['B']+df['C']
df['A_k'] = np.random.rand(n,1)
df['B_k'] = np.random.rand(n,1)
df['C_k'] = np.random.rand(n,1)
df['A_k'] = df['A_k'] * df['A']
df['B_k'] = df['B_k'] * df['B']
df['C_k'] = df['C_k'] * df['C']
```

Each customer can be activated either on "A" or on "B" or on "C" and only if the Boolean related to the type of activation is equal to 1.

In input i have the count of the final activations. es:

```
Target_A = 500
Target_B = 250
Target_C = 250
```

With this code i want to minimize the distance between the count of real activation and the input data.

```
A = LpVariable.dicts("A", range(0, n), lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat='Boolean')
B = LpVariable.dicts("B", range(0, n), lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat='Boolean')
C = LpVariable.dicts("C", range(0, n), lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat='Boolean')

prob = LpProblem("problem",LpMaximize)

#objective
prob += lpSum(A)+lpSum(B)+lpSum(C)

#constraints
prob += Target_A >= lpSum(A)
prob += Target_B >= lpSum(B)
prob += Target_C >= lpSum(C)

for idx in range(0, n):
    prob += A[idx] + B[idx] + C[idx] <= 1 #cant activate more than 1
    prob += A[idx] <= df['A'][idx] #cant activate if 0
    prob += B[idx] <= df['B'][idx] 
    prob += C[idx] <= df['C'][idx]

prob.solve()
```

how can I minimize the distance from the input distribution (as shown in the code above) and at the same time maximize the weight of the activations 'A_k', 'B_k', 'C_k'?

p.s. The random values in code are an input for the optimizer and represent the possibility or not to activate the client in that way. 
I can associate the client with only one "way" in order to respect the final target

Comment: how is this question different from your previous one?

Comment: yeah, now I want to minimize the distance and maximize the associated weight for each activation :)

Comment: Each customer has an associated weight of activation for A, B and C?

Comment: yes, activation A has A_k as associated weight, b has B_k and C has C_k.
Each client has different weights on the various activations

Comment: Your current code could not be activating a customer that can be activated because you are not allowing 501 A to be activated

Comment: I tried to rewrite your code in the other question to adapt it to the weights, but I couldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55610242/how-can-i-minimize-the-distance-from-a-given-input-distribution/55620451#55620451) you only need to modify 1 line: the objective function. In order to give priority to the absolute difference first, and only in case of a draw prioritize a solution with more weight, we will just scale the difference in the objective function so that even getting 1 difference less, would be better than any weight improvement. We can do this by scaling against the amount of customers + 1, as the sum of weights can never be more than n.

So just use old code and change objective function to:

```
prob += (O1 + O2 + O3) * (n + 1) - lpSum([A[idx] * df['A_k'][idx] + B[idx] * df['B_k'][idx] + C[idx] * df['C_k'][idx] for idx in range(0, n)])
```

You will now need to manually check the variables and their assignment to know the difference value, as the objective solution represents another thing.